# How to delete and clear the datagridview rows in vb 2010

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am developing a Point of Sale System in VB and using access as RDBMS. Everything went well however when it came to deletion i got stuck. **I want to clear all the rows from the datagridview and want to delete it from database also.** The new datagridview will store new items and i am sending that new data to print.I tried the below codes but all in vain.

```
     Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        For i As Integer = 0 To SProductDataGridView.RowCount
             SProductDataGridView.Rows.Remove(SProductDataGridView.Rows(0))
         Next

     End Sub
```

**2nd Try**

```
For i As Integer = 0 To SProductDataGridView.RowCount -1 
          ProductTableAdapter.DeleteProduct(IDTextBox.Text)
          ProductTableAdapter.Fill(MyDS.product)
          ProductTableAdapter.Dispose()
     Next
```

**Note :** `gridview.rows.clear() + gridview.ds` = nothing , i tried that butgridview.rows.clear() doesn't work and gridview.ds = nothing just clear the gridview and is not deleting data from access database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of below options:

- Using DataTable
- Using DataGridView
- Using BindingSource

The logic of all solutions is removing the rows and then updating the table adapter.

**Using DataTable**

You can find each rows in the data table and delete it, then update the table adapter:

```
For Each row As DataRow In Me.TestDBDataSet.TestTable.Rows
    row.Delete()
Next
Me.TestTableTableAdapter.Update(TestDBDataSet.TestTable)
```

**Using DataGridView**

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.TestTableDataGridView.Rows
    DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Delete()
Next
Me.TestTableTableAdapter.Update(TestDBDataSet.TestTable)
```

**Using BindingSource**

```
For Each item As Object In TestTableBindingSource
    TestTableBindingSource.Remove(item)
Next
Me.TestTableTableAdapter.Update(TestDBDataSet.TestTable)
```

Comment: at this line (For Each row As DataRow In Me.SProductDataGridView.sProduct.Rows) it gives this error (Error 'sProduct' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'. ) sProduct is TestTable in my database.

Comment: I used `For Each row As DataRow In Me.TestDBDataSet.TestTable.Rows` not datagridview. You can also use datagridview but the code will be a bit different.